# is it possible to do non custodial staking with pnfts (freeze accounts)?

Tags: metaplex, nft, staking

pnfts are in frozen accounts by default, and only metaplex program can thaw / freeze them again.

But then, my question is : is it possible to do non custodial staking ? If i can't freeze the account by myself, what will make a wallet to wallet transfer not possible then ? (and the idea is not to block ALL wallet to wallet transfers, only staked nfts)

of course there is the solution to follow the activity of the nft to stop the staking, but trying to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

It is! There's a specific delegate for this on pNFTs called the staking delegate. It locks the token at the Token Metadata level. Here are the docs.
https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/delegates#staking-delegate-pnft-only